# How could I sort a csv file in multiple ways in one go?

Tags: python, csv, sorting

I'm supposed to write a program where I take any csv file and sort them any of four different ways, alphabetically, by item id, old to recent, or most expensive to least expensive. I figured out how to open any csv file in general, now my issue is how I even begin to sort it.

So far I have this:

```
import csv 
input = input('')
with open(input, 'r') as csvfile:
     csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
     for row in csv_reader:
         print(row)
```

And then I used a while True statement after to create a menu of options to allow a user to select how they wanted everything sorted because that was the only way I could grasp how to write this. Now I'm stuck and I'm only a newbie to python. I'm only allowed to use the list.sort function in order to make it all work. If anyone has any tips, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: what's up with `input = input('')`?

Comment: Are you allowed to use any libraries? Pandas seems like it would be useful here.

Comment: Ahh that was a mistake, I changed it so that it could prompt the user to write in an input.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use `input` as the variable name since `input` itself is the function name for asking input.

Secondly, your question is how you can store up the csv file content in your code so that you can reuse it in each sort. One way is to put it in a list,

```
import csv 
filename = input() # change the variable name
csv_content = []
with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
     csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
     for row in csv_reader:
         print(row)
         csv_content.append(row)
```

then you do all sorts of things to this `csv_content` list, like applying `sort` by `csv_content.sort()`

Comment: This was actually very helpful and a great push in the right correction, thank you so much.